# SSDT not working with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 and imported a project which has a .rptproj file for the SSRS that it outputs, and it's consistently labeled as "incompatible." As per all the other posts about this kind of issue, I've updated the Database Tools in Visual Studio, as well as trying to get the download directly from the MSDN website. Every form of updating SSDT has left the file as incompatible still, so I'm not sure what might be going on in my setup that I could be missing.

Comment: I assume you are targeting SQL Server 2014 or earlier?

Comment: 2014 SQL Server, that's correct!

Comment: Just answered, you need the VS Update 2 RC as well. Run into the same issues after updating.

Answer (score 1):

You need both the latest SSDT version (14.0.60305)  *and* Visual Studio Update 2 RC to work with SSRS and SSIS. Annoyingly, this wasn't mentioned in the blog post that announced the latest SSDT version.

After installing both I was able to move all my SSIS and SSRS projects targeting SQL Server 2014 to VS 2015. If I remember correctly, the latest SSDT version solved the script component incompatibiblity in SSIS, and VS Update 2 RC fixed incompatibility issues for SSRS.

Make sure you target SQL Server 2014 in your project properties, as by default they target SQL Server 2016

Comment: Awesome - I'll update to RC2! In the mean time, as I'm still somewhat unfamiliar with some of the IDE features, could you perhaps detail where I would look at "project properties" to target the database version? I would normally assume the properties window in the main display when a project is open, but I'd be remiss if I overlooked something else as well

Comment: Right-click on your SSRS project and click Properties. You'll see that there is a new setting called TargetServerVersion that allows you to target different SSRS versions. This doesn't require Update 2 RC but doesn't actually work correctly without it

Comment: I downloaded Update 2 from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx and restarted everything, yet my reports project is still listed as being incompatible. I don't see any updates either in the IDE that it says I am missing. Any other thoughts? (Right clicking on the report project just gives me the option of edit, delete, and reload by the way)

Comment: I also did just notice that, in my Programs and Features, Visual Studio is listed as "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1" which, to me, means that even though I installed the update and reset, it didn't update to 2?

Comment: What is the error message? As for the update version, you can find it in the `Help->About` dialog box. "Programs and Features" shows program names, not the installed updates. You probably installed a VS version that already included Update 1.